# Django get primary key with JSON response

Tags: json, django, ajax

How do I send each objects primary key with JSON response?
I am sending json response to amend a table based on users state. Everything works fine, except not being able to get the PK associated with each user.

Currently its sending all values except PK.

```
class UserByState(View):
page_limit = 100

def get_paginated_context(self, queryset, page, limit):
    if not page:    page = 1 
    
    if limit:   
        self.page_limit = limit  
    paginator = Paginator(queryset, self.page_limit)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)
    serialized_page = serialize("json", page_obj.object_list)
    serialized_page = [obj["fields"] for obj in json.loads(serialized_page)]

    return {
        "data": serialized_page,
        "pagination": {
            "page": page,
            "limit": limit,
            "has_next": page_obj.has_next(),
            "has_prev": page_obj.has_previous(),
            "total": queryset.count()
        }
    }

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = self.request.user
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    limit = request.GET.get('limit')
    state = request.GET.get('state')
    
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    if state and state != "all":
        queryset = queryset.filter(state=state)

    to_return = self.get_paginated_context(queryset, page, limit)
    return JsonResponse(to_return, status = 200)
```

Comment: I think this comprehension may lose some values. Can you check (print) both variables `serialized_page`?

`serialized_page = serialize("json", page_obj.object_list)`

`serialized_page = [obj["fields"] for obj in json.loads(serialized_page)]`

Comment: Printing returns: {"model": "users.user", "pk": 767137, "fields": {"first_name": "Dan", "last_name": "ram", "address": "6090 DRAGON WAY", "city": "CREST", "state": "CA", "zipcode": 91912}}   I am trying to get the pk when amending the table and am only getting the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this comprehension may lose some values.

`serialized_page = serialize("json", page_obj.object_list)`

When you call `['fields']` here:

`serialized_page = [obj["fields"] for obj in json.loads(serialized_page)]`

You get only values of key 'fields'. It's like standard dictionary.

```
fields = {"first_name": "Dan", "last_name": "ram", "address": "6090 DRAGON WAY", "city": "CREST", "state": "CA", "zipcode": 91912}
```

Try that:

```
serialized_page = serialize("json", page_obj.object_list)
serialized_page = [{**obj["fields"], **{"pk": obj["pk"]}} for obj in json.loads(serialized_page)]
```

Comment: When I print(serialized_page) I get: {"model": "users.user", "pk": 767137, "fields": {"first_name": "Dan", "last_name": "ram", "address": "6090 DRAGON WAY", "city": "CREST", "state": "CA", "zipcode": 91912}} how do I print both?

Comment: Just call print(serialized_page) after one, then after another ;)

Comment: It has the PK there, but when I console log in my amend table jquery function it only gives me the fields.

Comment: If you don't understand dictionaries, you will not understand serializers.

Comment: When I use serialized_page = serialize("json", page_obj.object_list)
serialized_page = [{**obj["fields"], **{"pk": obj["pk"]}} for obj in serialized_page]   I get TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Corrected last row.

Comment: serialized_page = [{**obj["fields"], **{"pk": obj["pk"]}} for obj in json.loads(serialized_page)] worked. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome.